# How to migrate Site Custom Content types to centralized Content type gallery in SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, modern-experience, content-type-hub, custom-content-type

Is there a way to migrate/move SharePoint Online custom content types which were created in site to centralized Content Type Gallery?

I have a site with site content types and I would like to make them available to other sites in my tenant? What would be the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the **Content type hub** in SharePoint.

Check below documentations for more information:

1. [Publish a content type from a content publishing hub](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/publish-a-content-type-from-a-content-publishing-hub-58081155-118d-4e7a-9cc5-d43b5dbb7d02)
2. [Content Type Hub In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/content-type-hub-in-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: With **Content type hub** It is possible only to publish Content Types from Hub to Sites. My question is a bit different.

Comment: Yes, to publish & reuse the content type. I don't think it is possible to migrate/move custom content types. You have to re-create it, either manually or using scripting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had several content types that had been created on a project site and it was decided to they needed to be available for all projects. I used the ShareGate application (Copy Content and Structure) to copy the needed content types from the source project site to the internal SharePoint online content type hub (https://your tenant/sites/contenttypehub/). I'm sure this could also be accomplished using PowerShell. When the copy was complete I published the content types through SharePoint Admin > Content Services > Content Type Gallery. After publication, I was able to add the new content type using the add column menu in my library.